# What is the exact specification (allowed/forbidden characters) for Azure AD App Client Secrets?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm talking about this step https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#authentication-two-options , option 2: "Create a new application secret"

I'm particularly interested if there is a list of allowed / not allowed characters, so that I can rely on some specific character that it will **not** be in a secret...

**LATER EDIT:**
The reason for the question is that I need to programmatically store these values somewhere, and do some operations concatenate/base64encode/split/etc...
**So what I need, bottom-line**, is to know what character I can use as a splitter to store the appId and the secret.

Anybody knows of such specification ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The character set for secrets is by the regular expression [-_.~a-zA-Z0-9]{,40}.

This comes from the [Microsoft Purview documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/sit-defn-azure-ad-client-secret?view=o365-worldwide).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such allowed or not allowed list for generating secrets.

The secret value will be generated by azure AD. you just need to give the name(description) and expiry date
[image]

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough on the question, I edited now to specify exactly what I need.